# Component's prop value isn't showing in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a clone of Spotify where I'm using `Spotify-web-API` to access all the user data (id, name, playlist info, etc.) And to avoid prop drilling all these data are getting stored in `Datalayer` with the help of `React-Context-api`. I have a component `Sidebar.js` where all the playlist names are getting pulled from the API and will be shown in the sidebar. Inside this component, I also have another component `SidebarOption.js` to show names of playlists. Although I'm getting the playlist names from the API but when I passed those in the `SidebarOption.js` component as `title` prop it isn't showing there. I also console logged the names to be sure. The names are showing in my console but not through the mapping function in SidebarOption component. I've attached a screenshot of what I'm getting in this link [Screenshot of console log](https://ibb.co/VtvbLQ4).

You'll see that outside the mapping function any prop value passed in the `SidebarOption` component is showing but not the ones inside the mapping function. So any help would be appreciated.

**Sidebar.js**

```
function SideBar() {
  const [{ playlists }, dispatch] = UseDataLayerValue();
  console.log("user playlist from sidebar.js", playlists);

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <img
        className="sidebar__logo"
        src="https://getheavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/spotify2019-830x350.jpg"
        alt="spotify-logo"
      />
      <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={SearchIcon} title="Search" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title="Your Library" />
      <br />
      <strong className="sidebar__title">PLAYLISTS</strong>
      <hr />

      {playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => {
        console.log(playlist.name);
        <h2>hi</h2>;
        <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SidebarOption.js**

```
function SidebarOption({ title, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div className="sidebarOption">
      {Icon && <Icon className="sidebarOption__icon" />}
      {Icon ? <h4>{title}</h4> : <p>{title}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is, you're using a map. But, you're not returning the value.

You have:

```js
 {playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => {
        console.log(playlist.name);
        <h2>hi</h2>;
        <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />;
      })}
```

Should be:

```js
{playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => {
  console.log(playlist.name);
  <h2>hi</h2>;
  return <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />;
})}
```

Here is the Codesandbox to notice:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sun-iku99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, But I thought when you're using arrow functions it automatically returns something. That's where I was wrong I guess

Comment: In the case of arrow functions what you're saying is true. but only if you don't use `{}`, So, you have: `myFuction = () => ThisIsReturned`, and also you have: `mySecondFunction = () => { thisIsNOTRetunred; return butThisIsReturned; }`

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that you are not returning the   SidebarOption in the map function you instead can do it like that

```
{playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => {
        console.log(playlist.name);
        return (
          <>
            <h2>hi</h2>;
            <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />;
          </>
        );
      })}
```

or

```
  {playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => (
        <>
          <h2>hi</h2>;
          <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />;
        </>
      ))}
```